# Is refraction a type of transmission?

Tags: optics, refraction

I had read a passage somewhere stating that there are three possibilities when light falls on an object. It absorbs some of it, reflects some of it and transmits some (pass through). However, I did not see refraction as a possible fate and was curious if refraction simply fell under transmission as both involve light passing through a medium

Comment: which two terms?

Comment: could you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between refraction of light through a medium and transmission of light through a medium (if there is any difference). I had read a passage somewhere stating that there are three possibilities when light falls on an object. It absorbs some of it, reflects some of it and transmits some (pass through). However, I did not see refraction as a possible fat and was curious if refraction simply fell under transmission.

Comment: one is the subset of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmitted light is refracted. How much depends on the angle of incidence and the difference in the indices of refraction in both media.

Therefore, as QuIcKmAtHs has pointed out already, refraction is just a special case of transmission.

To describe the behavior of light on an object even more detailed, we introduce finer distinctions as to what happens with the light: it can be refracted, scattered, attenuated, filtered, diffracted, etc. It's often just useful to group these together into reflection, transmission and absorbtion.